# Unable to convert the base64 data to file using jszip in javascript

Tags: javascript, jszip

i have a base64 data coming via api and it is a tar file and i am trying to download using jszip but i am getting error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Can't read the data of <base64 code>
```

below is my code

```
let bs = <somebase64code>
     let zip = new JSZip();


     zip.file(bs,{base64:true})

    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
      saveAs(content, "example");
    });
```

[image]

as the base64 code is large i havent attached it

Answer (score 1):

jszip don't deal with tar files
tar and zip are not the same format
You need to use some other lib or use zip instead in the api

Also don't use base64, it will be <s>~3x</s> ~33% larger in size.

Comment: Not 3x, just 33%.  But still, don't use base64.

Comment: @brad ok what is the best approach then and is there any lib for handling tar files ?

Comment: @Endless is there any lib for handling tar files and instead of base 64 which approach is better?

Comment: @Dexter Many.  https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=tar&ranking=maintenance  And instead of dealing with base64, use regular binary data.  You should nag the API provider about this.